# Android service periodically performing tasks in background?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service, android-background

I have created an Android Service which I start simply in my activity

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.abc.app", MyService.class.getName());
startService(i);
bindService(i, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Then I use onServiceConnected callback to get my service instance, so I can call its functions

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder boundService) {
            myService = IMyInterface.Stub.asInterface((IBinder) boundService);
        }
```

I can successfully call the functions and can get the results. But I want my service to perform a task periodically in background (like a function which will be called after every few minutes) I can't call function from my activity because I finish() my activity after starting the service and I want my service to simply run in background and perform a task.

Comment: y  u are not using alarm service with repeat mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add а TimerTask, see how to do that [here](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2012/07/07/create-a-service-that-does-a-schedule-task/)